# Simple.Data Micro ORM with Intellisense in Visual Studio (dynamics)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, simple.data, micro-orm

I've decided to use [Simple.Data Micro ORM](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data#readme) for it's simplicity to work with database and save me writing quite a lot of code and Id don't even need to create the object due to dynamics!

The thing is that I lose Intellisense support in Visual Studio, and I don't like to take a look at the row names every time I write the code. Is there any way to utilize intellisense with dynamics, even in  patchy way?

So they question might be whether it's possible to have intellisense with dynamics in one way or another?

Comment: Dynamics are resolved at runtime, while intellisense deals with static analysis, so unfortunately not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, once you start using Simple.Data you do lose intellisense. However, [as detailed on Mark Rendle's blog](http://blog.markrendle.net/2012/10/12/howto-dial-up-the-static-on-simple-data/), it is possible to use a project called [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) to dial it back in.

Comment: The link above to Mark's blog entry is broken.  The page is available here: http://blog.markrendle.net/howto-dial-up-the-static-on-simple-data/

Answer (score 2):

There is a very patchy project on my GitHub called [Simple.Data.Pad](http://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data.Pad) which you can use to write queries with some database-derived code completion; you can copy and paste them into Visual Studio when you're done.

I'm expecting to deliver a better, VS-integrated solution next year.